# Real form and real structure on a complex Lie group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

E.B.Vinberg and A.L.Onishchik in their [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=TV7sCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=real%20form%20and%20real%20structure&source=bl&ots=Z1jxruqogp&sig=nmKix-DFWTL-52qBbob2nw76PU4&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=MZ5eVb7dKsT-ygOOpIGAAw&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=real%20form%20and%20real%20structure&f=false) give the following two definitions.

1. For a complex Lie group $G$ its real Lie subgroup $H$ is called a *real form* of $G$, if

   a) the Lie algebra $L(H)$ of $H$ is a real form of the Lie algebra
   $L(G)$ of $G$, and

   b) $H$ has nonzero intersection with each connected component of $G$
2. A (continuous) homomorphism $S:G\to G$ (of a complex Lie group $G$) is called a *real structure* on $G$, if

   a) $S(S(g))=g$, for $g\in G$, and

   b) the corresponding mapping of the Lie algebra $d S:L(G)\to L(G)$ is a real structure (another term: an involution) on $L(G)$.

It is known that on a *connected complex Lie group* (or on an *irreducible algebraic group*) $G$ for each real structure $S:G\to G$ the subgroup of stable elements
$$
H=\{g\in G:\ Sg=g\}
$$
is a real form on $G$, and the Lie algebra $L(H)$ coincides with the set of stable elements for $dS$:
$$
L(H)=\{x\in L(G):\ dS(x)=x\}.
$$

My question:

> Is this a one-to-one correspondence between real forms and real structures (for a reasonable class of groups)?

In particular,

> if $H$ is a real form of a complex a Lie group $G$, does there always exist a real structure $S:G\to G$ such that $H$ is the subgroup of stable elements for $S$ in $G$, and $L(H)$ is the subspace of stable elements for $dS$ in $L(G)$?

This is strange, I can't find a reference, even for the case, when

> $H$ is a compact real Lie group, and $G$ is its complexification.

(Actually, that would be enough for me.)

I would be grateful for anybody's help.

Comment: I asked this also at MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207271/real-form-and-real-structure-on-a-complex-lie-group